# how to merge multiple files in multiple directories

Tags: bash

I have two sets of files with the following patterns:

- original file: /etc/virtual/DOMAIN_NAME/aliases
- modified file: /home/user/files/DOMAIN_NAME/aliases

where the DOMAIN_NAME is dynamic and is a domain name ;) which is the same in both location, and here is my problem. I need to combine 2 files like this:

cat /home/user/files/aaa.com/aliases >> /etc/virtual/aaa.com/aliases

But I have about 400 domains in the /home/user/files, can anyone help me how to merge aliases file from 2 different directories.

Answer (score 0):

In the below script, I am extracting the domain and then using it to construct the target aliases file

```
#!/bin/bash

find /home/user/files -type f -name aliases | while read file; do 
    domain=$(echo $file | awk -F/ '{print $5}')
    echo ">> Processing $domain"
    cat $file >> /etc/virtual/${domain}/aliases
done
```